# Number of network connections possible

Tags: sockets, connection, port

Since port numbers are limited to 65536, is there a limit for the connection num?

How does each connection differs from each other?

If it's by port,then there can never been more than 65536 connections at the same time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's many different pieces in play. Since a connection is defined by `(Src IP, Src Port, Dest IP, Dest Port)` tuples, you're allowed 65536 ^ 2 connections between two given peers at any given time: from 1 to 1, from 1 to 2, .. from 1 to 65535, etc. And that's just between two peers -- you can of course have many connections open to many peers simultaneously.

**BUT**, most operating systems limit the number of open filedescriptors / handles per process. This limit was historically low (20), but is now often higher (1024 on my system, `ulimit -a` will show per-process limits in `bash(1)`).

In addition to the `setrlimit(3)` limits on Unix systems, there are also system-wide limits; `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` on a Linux system will report the maximum number of open files allowed on the entire system. (This is 596118 on my system.) Other systems will have different limits.

And, there may be a limit to the number of open connections enforced by a [stateful firewall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall) in the middle. Since each state requires memory in the firewall tables, any will probably enforce some arbitrary limit to avoid running short on memory.

Comment: `65536 ^ 2 ` is the number of connections between **2 specified** IP,right?

Comment: You don't need to raise the number of file descriptors to use up a lot of ports because sockets LINGER around after they are closed.

Comment: @DriverBoy, yes, that's the theoretical maximum between two IP addresses. In practice, the maximum can be lower.

Comment: @DriverBoy, correct, that's the limit between two specific IPs. If your local machine has more IPs, then you get to double it. If the remote peer has more IPs, then you get to double it again. If both peers have two IPs, that's 262140 TCP sessions that you can have open simultaneously between those two machines.

Comment: @sarnold,Is it possible to get the tuple elements(source/dest IP/ports) given a socket fd?

Comment: @DriverBoy, yes, it is possible to get the whole tuple: use `getpeername(2)` to find the _remote_ IP and port, and `getsockname(2)` to find the _local_ IP and port. See `ip(7)` for details on the `struct sockaddr` that will contain the address and port number. (And `ntohs(3)` to convert the port from network endian to host endian.)

Answer (score 7):

A TCP connection is actually identified by peer IP address + peer port + local IP address + local port, so you could actually have way more than 64k, but I don't know if OSs do the work to allow more than 64k per local IP address. Windows doesn't.

One thing of interest is that ports can remain reserved for a short while after they are closed. (This is done to avoid accidental or intentional crosstalk between old and new connections.) By simply creating and closing a connection on tight loop, you can actually make your machine run out of ports. See http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=897591 for Perl code that will hang socket connection calls (on some machines) by using up all the sockets.

UDP also has ports, but UDP doesn't have connections. The socket is therefore identified only by its local IP address + local port, so one can have a maximum of 64k UPD ports on the go per local IP address.

**Update**: Added paragraph on UDP.