# Should my all web applications run on port 80 in web server?

Tags: server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y72Dl.png)I'm new in programming, and just begin to learn about Servers. I'm confused about following. Say I have a Web server that I am using for my website. My questions are followings:

-How many ports do I have at this web server? Also 65536 as in "normal" server or less

-Do I have to use ONLY port 80 to communicate with this server (because of HTTP)?

-All my web applications are hosted in port 80? If so it means that I’m using only one port?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Right http usualy connects to port 80, https to 443

Comment: It means that all my web applications are nested in port 80? It really confuses me.

Comment: Yes, on the server side of the connection

Comment: How about other ports? I don't use the at all? Since web servers main job is to deal with web pages

Comment: At least not for "web pages". Additionally you may need 53 for dns and maybe 22 for ssh.. Perhaps this post helps you clarify: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945695/number-of-network-connections-possible

Comment: I have added picture. Please review it. It says that you can use only one server app per port. It means that I cannot put more than one web application in port 80. This part is confusing to me

Comment: You can put as many web apps or websites on a particular server as your resources (ram/cpu/networkbandwidth) can handle. A (physical) server could for example be responsible for serving the websites of serveral domain. The webserver (for example appache or nginx) "knows" from the request which site he has to serve for a particular request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use additional ports for your server. Add the portnumber with a colon to the url:

```
http://www.example.com:8080
```

Make sure that you don't have a firewall that blocks this port.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but I'll try to answer as best I can:

1. Which ports are available to you will depend on the server configuration. There is (conceptually) nothing particularly special about a server except in how it's used. You could theoretically use any ports that are not already in use or blocked by a firewall (higher port 1024 is usually pretty safe; higher than port 10000 is almost certainly safe). This is something that you will have to configure in your web server software (e.g. Apache, nginx, IIS, etc)
2. You can use any unused port you want. Port 80 is the default for unencrypted HTTP traffic, while port 443 is the default for encrypted HTTPS traffic. Ports 8080 and 8888 are other common ones used as alternate ports for web server traffic.
3. This is up to you. It is possible to configure all your websites to run on the same port, differentiated by their hostname (for example, [Apache Virtual Hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/)) or you could use a separate port for each website. The advantage of virtual hosting is that users don't have to specify the port number in the URL. For example, if you host example.com on port 8080, then the user would need to navigate to http://example.com:8080 in order to access your site.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the exact number of ports available on a server but definitely in the thousands.

You can use any port you like but traditionally port 80 is used for "regular" http traffic and 443 for secure traffic, 21 for FTP, etc.

Here's a list of commonly used ports:
http://support.hostgator.com/articles/commonly-used-port-numbers

You can host multiple websites on a single server, all using port 80 for as long as the server supports HTTP 1.1 protocol - pretty much all modern servers do. If you stick to these commonly used ports, you may not need to worry about additional configuration in other places such as your firewall, etc.

Comment: Thank your for your response. You said that I can host multiple websites in one server that are using the same port. Do I host those websites on different ports? Say one on 1002 and the other on 1003?

Comment: As I said in my answer, they can all use port 80 if your server supports HTTP 1.1 protocol. Unless you're using a really old web server, it should support HTTP 1.1. Here's the reason: the server needs a way to take incoming web request and send it to the right website. HTTP 1.1 supports  host headers which contains the domain name of the site w.g. MySite.com. With this the server knows where to direct the request to. If your server doesn't support HTTP 1.1 protocol, then each website hosted on your server would have to use a different port number.

Comment: Sam in the book that I'm reading it says                                                         ""Now let’s assume that our simple web site is using Apache (the extremely popular, open source web server you’re probably already using). What would the directory structure look like for a web site called www.wickedlysmart.com, hosting two applications, one giving skiing advice, and the other beer-related advice? Imagine that the Apache application is running on port 80."

Comment: So in this case we have 3 application, right? one Apache application and 2  others Advice applications? Each running on different port

Comment: I typically create a folder in which I keep all my websites - say "Websites". I then create individual folders for each website e.g. MyBeerSite, SomeWebsite, OtherWebsite, etc. Each individual folder becomes the root folder for its respective website. The location of these folders is up to you. As you setup each website on the web server, you simply point to its root folder e.g. MyBeerSite and define its domain e.g. mybeersite.com